# Can I use a pc case fan for a tumble dryer?

Tags: amperage, fan

My tumble dryer is broken. I found the service manual online and according to the error number the heat pump fan is the problem. I open it up and to my surprise I found a standard sized case fan in 92x92x25 dimensions.

It is labeled with: NMB-mat 7 3610VL-04W , 0.40A, 12V. The error message says that the fan is below 1200 rpms. Which is quite true because it doesn't work at all. So my question is:

**Is it possible to use a standard 92mm case fan? The Voltage is also 12V but how about the amperage? Does it have to match?**

I would buy one with a 3 pin plug and replace it with the (proprietary?) one of the original. It needs to thave more than 1200 rpms of course. I found the original spare part however in another country and quite pricey...

Comment: Repair question so **off topic**. Also, there is **no one here** that will tell you anything else than to replace the fan with an **identical model** as only that model is **guaranteed** to provide the right amount of airflow that is needed for the dryer. Some 1200 rpm fans provide **more** airflow than other 1200 rpm fans so only looking at the rpm is meaningless.

Comment: I would personally investigate swapping the blades from the original to the new fan assembly, making sure the other characteristics match... but the other commenter is correct...

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie "Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired." It seems to me we are well on topic here.

Comment: I have not yet come across a single tumble dryer which does not have a second line of defence in case something fails, usually a thermal cutoff or thermal fuse. If I where you, I would try to match or go above the original fan power (current). You can also compare the pitch of the fins and number of them to determine if you are resonable similar in the pressure-air flow curve or just compare datasheets.

Answer (score 2):

The part number you quote "3610VL-04W" is for a fairly standard 12V plastic case fan, with a rated highest operating temperature of 70C and a speed of 5600rpm. 70C seems to be the standard maximum for no-name budget case fans so you should be fine. Be aware that the pinout might be different (non PC applications often swap the 12V and the tacho pins over), and make sure the replacement fan has the same or equivalent fire rating. You should pick something which approximately matches the 96.4 CFM rating and the back pressure rating (150Pa). However given the controller hasn't complained until the fan got down to 1200rpm from 5900, I suspect you've got quite a lot of leaway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any fan you want, but results may vary.

You need to match the voltage input, so use a fan rated for 12 V. The current is a bit trickier. Assuming the worst, the fan driver is capable of delivering just 0.4 A, so the fan you pick needs to absorb at most 0.4 A.

The RPM are read through the third wire, it is possible that this particular manufacturer uses a proprietary protocol, but I would find it quite surprising. Odds are that the fan in there is just an off the shelf solution, and not an high quality one, since it broke.

Now to the real part of the answer: a drier is an appliance that manages a lot of power. I did not exactly understood what this fan is supposed to cool down, but if the appliance errors out, odds are it is something that really needs to be cooled down.

To be sure that the new fan is enough, RPM is just an hint, the important figure is how much air it moves over time. If you decide to buy an aftermarket replacement, please buy something with a current consumption as near as possible to 0.4 A, odds are the more current, the more air it moves. And monitor your appliance after the fix, see if it gets unusually hot or something.